# Installer, self extractor?

Tags: deployment, setup-deployment

I have a list of photos and a photo viewer application (and executable) that I'd like to package as an installer file. What tools can I use to package all the files together, instruct the installer where to copy files to, to automatically run the executable, etc.? An MSI-like installer would be ideal, I think.

Comment: What programming language? What operating system?

Comment: This is not the place for such a question but http://www.chilkatsoft.com/chilkatsfx.asp will do the job for you

Answer (score 0):

[There is a list of Install software on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software). Eliminate those that don't suit your platform/licensing/budget/are discontinued and you should end up with a small list enough to try all of them.